# CakePHP plugin for login, ACL management

Tags: cakephp

What is a well-established plugin in Cakephp 3.8 that can manage login functions, permissions for each role, etc.? I'm looking for a popular plugin with a high update frequency.
I am searching for it on the Internet, and I would like to hear the opinions of everyone with knowledge.

Thank you.

Comment: Visual ACL Manager for CakePHP 3.8

Comment: Questions asking for opinions are considered offtopic on stackoverflow, you're better off asking in the CakePHP [**forums**](https://discourse.cakephp.org/) or the [**slack channel**](https://cakesf.herokuapp.com/).